# angular2 ngRepeat to loop through xml data

Tags: javascript, xml, foreach, angular

I've converted my xml data into json format for my angular2 to be called in my view. I have few data in my xml so I need to loop through it to but doing `for(var...` its says `cannot find name array` and property `lenght` does not exist on type Document.

```
getXml() {
   this.http.get('../../xmlConf/dashboard_journey.xml')
    .map(response => response.text())
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");

            for (var index = 0; index < xmlData.length; index++) {
                var element = xmlData[index];

            }
        }
    });
}
```

this line will return the xml data which will I need to loop through

```
var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
```

XML Data I have 5 of this:

```
<journey>
<title>Click and Collect</title>
<shortDesc>
    <short_desc_1>lorem</short_desc_1>
    <short_desc_2>lorem</short_desc_2>
</shortDesc>
<longDesc>
    lorem
</longDesc>
<imageName>
    <img src="/journey_images/clickandcollect.jpg" alt="Click and Collect"/>
</imageName>
```

What I wanted to have as endresult.

like in angular1 when interacting with json format data from the server you can access the items like `data.obj` or in html you can do an ng-repeat of the response data.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 <div>{{item.title}}</div>
 <div>{{item.longDesc}}</div>
 <div>{{item.imageName}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only loop over nodes in the document you get from the DOMParser.

With `var tags = xmlData. getElementsByTagName('journey')` you get all nodes and you can interate over them.

```
var node= xmlData.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    alert(node[i].nodeName + ' = ' + node[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: I will try this, I've updated my original post above regarding what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

`DOMParser.parseFromString` returns a [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) object.

First you need to decide what you want to loop through. For example, if you want to iterate over all `journey` tags, you can use:

```
var journeys = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('journey');
```

This will return a [collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) objects that you can iterate.

Comment: I will try this, I've updated my original post above regarding what I wanted to do.

Comment: You asked a question and got an answer (actually two answers). Then you change the question? If you have another question, you should ask another question. Don't update the original question with a follow-up after you got your answer.